# Queryset is not filtered although there is data in table?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

These are the contents in my Models.py

```
class InstituteType(models.Model):
    institute_type_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    institute_type_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    institute_type_description = models.TextField(max_length = 300)

class InstituteMasters(models.Model):
    institute_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    institute_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    institute_institute_type = models.ForeignKey(InstituteType,verbose_name="Institute Type")
    institute_district = models.ForeignKey(Districts, verbose_name = "District")
    institute_vdc_municipality = models.ForeignKey(VdcMunis,null=True,blank=True,verbose_name="VDC/Municipality")
    #.....

class InstituteInfos(models.Model):
    institute_info_id = models.OneToOneField(InstituteMasters,primary_key=True,verbose_name="Name of Institute",null=False)
    vision = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    mission = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    goal = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    #......
```

There is 3 rows in table related to model InstituteTypes.. 
institute_type_id;   institute_type_name;  institute_type_description
1                ;   Constituted        ; some_text
2                ;   TECS; some_text
3                ;   Affiliated; some_text

There are many rows in InstituteMasters table containing all 1,2,3 ids of InstituteTypes

But Interestingly! In python manage.py shell

```
>>> xx = InstituteInfos.objects.filter(institute_info_id__institute_institute_type__institute_type_id = 1)
>>> xx
```

returns objects

```
>>> xx = InstituteInfos.objects.filter(institute_info_id__institute_institute_type__institute_type_id = 2)
>>> xx
```

returns []

Why can't I filter InstituteInfos whose InstituteMasters have a field inistitute_institute_type set to 2?? Same code filters for type 1 and 3. If I filter from InstituteMasters, all 1,2,3 is returned.

Comment: the obvious answer would be that the particular combination you are filtering for does not exist in the db

Comment: Thanks @Anetropic. I had to rigorously go through my db. And found some data were absent during my import.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your design. The strongest advice I can give you is to read the Django docs and tutorial and do your models that way. The way you're doing this is a lot of extra work for no gain.

The particular problem you're encountering, I suspect, is that your institute_info_id field is doing double duty as a primary key and a foreign key. That's not an impossible design, but IMO it's an extremely brittle one.

Please consider some streamlining for readability. Wouldn't it be great if your models looked more like this?

```
class InstituteType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=300)

class InstituteMasters(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    institute_type = models.ForeignKey(InstituteType)
    #.....
```